# App not working on Android 6 with Angular 13

Tags: angular, android-6.0-marshmallow, angular13

Angular 13 App not working on Android 6,
But working fine on Android web browser.

Comment: You need "embed" the .html in a Cordova (or similar) to create an apk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.